# How to apply a created hover effect to multiple components and pages?

Tags: css, reactjs, tailwind-css

I created a hover effect and want to put it into other components. I'm using `nextjs` and `tailwindcss`. I want to use this hover effect all my pages' text.

css:

```
/*Hover Effect*/

.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.one,
.two {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  color: white;
}

.container:hover .one {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.container:hover .two {
  transform: translateY(0);
  color: dimgray;
}

.two {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}
```

And the components are as follows. All of the texts on this page as well as my other page content should be hovered over. Is there a way to keep this hover style so that I can apply it on any element just by giving the value or something ?

```
<nav>
        <div>
          <Image />
          <a>Logo</a>
        </div>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <a>Home</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a>Work</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a>About</a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a>Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
```

I tried to do it with styled components. but it didn't work for me.

```
import React from 'react';
import styled, { css } from 'styled-components';

const hoverEffect = css`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  color: white;

  .container:hover & {
    transform: translateY(-100%);
  }

  .container:hover ~ & {
    transform: translateY(0);
    color: dimgray;
  }

  .container ~ & {
    transform: translateY(100%);
  }
`;

const StyledOne = styled.a`
  ${hoverEffect}
`;

const StyledTwo = styled.a`
  ${hoverEffect}
`;

const Container = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
`;

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <StyledOne className="p-10 text-center text-2xl">Work</StyledOne>
      <StyledTwo className="p-10 text-center text-2xl">Work</StyledTwo>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: `.container:hover &` is an invalid selector since a parent cannot select itself via its own children. What do you mean by this?

Comment: import css for each of html pages?